# zip a folder using fzip

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to compress a folder into a .zip file. I'm using the FZip library. This is what i have so far:

```
var zip:FZip = new FZip();
zip.addFile("Users/Vincent/Desktop/test/", null);
```

The folder test on my desktop is the folder i want to compress.

Now i would like to zip that folder and place the zip file on my desktop but they are talking about byteArrays etc. and i have no idea how to do this.
Can someone please help me?[enter link description here](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example, to make it short I used a lot of anonymous functions.

```
package {
import deng.fzip.FZip;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.FileReferenceList;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class ZipTest extends Sprite {
    private var imageRefList : FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
    private var saveRef : FileReference = new FileReference();
    private var zipName : String = "someName.zip";

    public function ZipTest() {
        var someButton : Sprite = new Sprite();
        with(someButton.graphics) {
            beginFill(0x00ff00);
            drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            endFill();
        }
        addChild(someButton).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event : MouseEvent) : void {
            var saveZip : Function = function(zip : FZip) : void {
                var out : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                zip.serialize(out);

                saveRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e : Event) : void {
                    trace("done");
                });
                saveRef.save(out, zipName);
            };

            imageRefList.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function(e : Event) : void {
                var zip : FZip = new FZip();
                var count : int = imageRefList.fileList.length;
                for each (var image: FileReference in imageRefList.fileList) {
                    image.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e : Event) : void {
                        var img : FileReference = FileReference(e.target);
                        trace(count + " loaded... " + img.name);
                        zip.addFile(img.name, img.data);

                        count--;
                        if (count == 0) saveZip(zip);
                    });
                    trace("load: " + image.name);
                    image.load();
                }
            });
            imageRefList.browse();
        });
    }
}
```

}