# Zip a folder in as3 Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, zip

I have created an Air app that after user interaction will creat a folder with bmp's, xml and text doc's.
All works apart from making the final zip which needs to be automatic.

I have been looking for a solution to this but cant find it.
Perhaps I am just not seeing it, and if so, can someone show me please.

My original posting on this is here --- 
[zip many files with Air as3 flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956573/zip-many-files-with-air-as3-flash)

---

The closest thing I have found was this one --- [zip a folder using fzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603199/zip-a-folder-using-fzip) 
But for some reason my coment was deleted which was --

> I like this. It is the closest I have come to a working solution to my own problem. That said, I tested this and it works nicely as is. Can this script be moded to run without interaction??? I am in need of it for a program that I have written. ANY asistance is welcom........ apart from just pointing me to Adobe referance as it dose not have anything like what I need. (well that I can see or find)

So now I am re-asking the comunity.

For some reason it will work with manual selection and manual save-to, but not aotonomusly.
There must be a workround to this even if it requires another full page of script.

====================================================================
UPDATE:
For closing this off, I have finally got my solution.
You can find it here. "[zip file contents have no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857925/zip-file-contents-have-no-data)".
Hope that my problem can help someone in the future.

Comment: You can use the nochump zip library for easy zip file creation and you can use FileStream and File objects to write directly to the file system without user interaction from AIR.

Comment: First I will admit that getting my head round the in's and out's of zipping has been a nightmare for me. I normaly see things quicker and find it easy to folow code, but this has me for now.

Comment: EDIT ---  NoChump and FZIP were the only ones I could find and not enough info and examples for me. Others might find them easy but the zipping side of things still makes it hard. As to letting the OS do it, I have that setup on the side already as a fall back, but do not realy want to do it. I want one program running to streemline everything as well as it would be bloat ware. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the as3 commons zip library.

http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/index.html

In order to do this you're going to need to load your directory, loop through all its contents and load each asset.

This code snippet includes a bulk loader to handle that for you.

**warning**

I pulled most of this code out of a project where I was doing something similar but I have not tested it as is. There may be some syntax errors!

```
private var zip:Zip;

zip = new Zip();


zip.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.createNewZip); //creates a new zip
zip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleZipLoaded); //loads the current zip, this is not shown here
zip.load(new URLRequest(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myZip.zip").url)); //path to your zip file
```

Method to create your new zip file

```
private function createNewZip(e:IOErrorEvent):void{

    trace("no zip");

    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myZip.zip"), FileMode.WRITE);

    zip.serialize(stream);
    stream.close();

}
```

You can use this to add all items in a directory to your zip file.

```
private function addDirToZip():void{

    var f:File = File.resolvePath("Your Dir");
    //this will be called when your directory listing has loaded
    f.addEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, handleDirLoaded);
    //you can also get the dir listing inline and not use a listener
    //doing it async will prevent ui lock
    f.getDirectoryListingAsync();

}
```

Next your going to need to load all of the files

```
protected function handleDirLoaded(e:FileListEvent):void{
    loadExternal = new Vector.<File>; //vector used to keep a handle on all files
    e.target.removeEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, handleDirLoaded);
    for(var i:int = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++){
        var f:File = files[i] as File;
        if(f.extension == "File Types you want"){  //you can do some file type checking here
              loadExternal.push(f);
        }

    }
   //start loading in the files
   loadFile();
}
```

This will go through the loadExternal vector and load all files

```
private function loadFile():void{
    currentFile = loadExternal.shift(); //returns the first item off the array

    //load the file
   var l:Loader = new Loader();
   l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaded);
   l.load(new URLRequest(currentFile.url));

}
```

Once each item is loaded you can store it for addition into the zip

```
private function handleLoaded(e:Event):void{

    var l:Loader = e.target.loader as Loader;
    l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaded);

    //storing everything in a dictionary 
    assets[currentFile.name] = l.content;

   //if we still have items to load go and do it all again

   if(loadExternal.length != 0){
        loadFile();
   } else {
       //now all files are loaded so lets add them to the zip
       addAssetsToZip();
   }

}
```

This is where all the loaded files actually get put into the zip and it is saved

```
private funcion addAssetsToZip():void{

   for(var fileName:String in assets){
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); //going to write this to the zip
        //make an object that holds the data and filename
        var data:Object = {};
        data.name = fileName;
        data.content = assets[fileName];
        ba.writeObject(data);
        //write this file to the zip
        zip.addFile(key, ba, false);
    }

    //and finally save everything out
    zip.close();
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myZip.zip"), FileMode.WRITE);
    zip.serialize(stream);
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a quick read of your code and it looks very promising. So will give it a go as soon as I have time.   :-)

Comment: I know it is a while now, but only just got the time to look at this. As I am using Flash Pro and not Flex as well as being still new to .swc files, I an finding it hard to setup and test. The .swc is in the library fine but I do not know what "Import" to use in my sript. I have also rurned the"private funcion "'s into regular Functions as they will only ron on one page at the end of everything. Is your code matched to the SWC calls?

Comment: f-a .... I have been going over the code and slowly serting put the compile errors. Two items still stand. Can you tell me what they are referancing or need to be please. Cant test the code properly till all errors are fixed. the ones in question are "assets" and "key" .

Comment: @Tempus assets is the name of a dictionary you need to declare. var assets:Dictionary = new Dictionary(). key is a unique string used to store the data in the zip

Comment: Just a comment, I seem to note freezing or file hanging when loading over 900 - 1200 files depending on the system.  Not sure if the File or Loader class is getting spammed and it causes some issues or not.  Trying to slow the loop down so it can load, callback and not hammer it to death.